# How to get time page loaded in (Edited)

Tags: jquery

I want to make loading effect until Document ready , It works but when page data is cached It shows for milliseconds and disappear as page content is cached , 
Like I want to show it if loading would be more than second at least

/** EDIT **/
I found out that animate effect is what make it appears , when I use remove() only it doesnt't show,
so I want to check time that page take to load and if it is more 3 sec I will apply animation

That is my code

```
     var ready = 0;
     $(document).ready(function(){
         ready = 1; 
     }); 

    if(ready = 1){
       $(".Loading").animate({opacity:"0"},"slow",function(){
       $(".Loading").remove();
      });
    }
```

Every time page loads the animate appears disappearing it and I don't want this ,
So what is best way to handle when it going to show?

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a function. It can't work in the way you try. It could look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   hideLoading(); 
}); 

function hideLoading() {
  $(".Loading").animate({opacity:"0"},"slow",function(){
    $(".Loading").remove();
  });
}
```